# how to write to a cell in xml strig that longer then 12 characters with vba

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to write it I get another string her is an example

I tried to write this:  `Range("A4").Value = "123456789123"`
and I get this: 1.23457E+11
if I enter to the cell so I get the real string but if I try to copy the all row so it copies the wrong string how can show the real string always?

Comment: Change the column formatting to `Number`, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is probably easier to change the format of the cell to TEXT before you add the value to it, then it will show the value as expected, to do this you can use the following line of code before `Range("A4").Value = "123456789123"` like below:

```
 Range("A4").NumberFormat = "@"
 Range("A4").Value = "123456789123"
```